# Click Link within .each loop in Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm working on a script to crawl a page of search results and I've created a loop to find the correct search result and that works. The issue I'm running into is that every permutation of trying to click on the link within the LI element doesn't work. At first I tried finding the anchor within the LI but it's a nokogiri object, I've tried going out into `@page` and drilling down to the correct element but it's coming back nil.

Is there a way to search within the LI element that I already drilled down to?

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

@agent = Mechanize.new do |agent|
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
end
@page = @agent.get('https://www.milwaukeetool.com/search-results?FullTextKeywords=48-42-5540')

def resultsPageSearcher (searchText)
  @page.search('#results ul > li').each do |li|
    results_sku = li.css('span.results-sku').text
    if results_sku == searchText
            link = @page.link_with(:text => results_sku)
      @page = link.click
    end
  end
end

resultsPageSearcher("48-42-5540")
```

Relevent LI Element (I cut out extraneous code that didn't seem relevant, I can add more if necessary I just didn't want to over post)

```
<li>
    <a href="/accessories/cutting/48-42-5540" class="results-image">
      <img src="//cdn.milwaukeetool.com/~/media/Images/Accessories/Cutting/48-42-5540/21867_48-42-5540.jpg?h=100&amp;thn=1&amp;w=100" alt=""></a>
    <a class="results-title" href="/accessories/cutting/48-42-5540">4" 10 TPI High-Carbon Steel Jig Saw Blade (5 PK)</a>            
    <span class="results-sku">48-42-5540</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about how it doesn't work? Are you seeing specific errors? If not, what result are you trying to get, and what is it giving you now?

Comment: @StevenSchobert It currently comes back NIL. This version of the code is where I ran out of ideas, I'd prefer not to go out to '@page' because I went through the trouble of drilling down to the correct LI element and I can't figure out how to find the link within just that element and click it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages and "[mcve]". You're asking us to imagine the HTML you're trying to navigate. Instead, reduce it to the absolute, bare minimum, and add that to the question formatted appropriately. That'll help us to work from the same input as you. Also, recreate the minimum code that demonstrates the problem using that HTML. Currently your question has code that doesn't relate to anything and we'll have to cobble up HTML to test which wastes our time.

Comment: @RyanStone Are you trying to get all of the link pages or all of the links under just a certain subsection of the page.

Comment: @TallPaul Just the subsection. The specific use case is the manufacturer doesn't supply my company data on their products and it would take me a week to manually input the data. I'm building this to crawl and grab the data. I'm inputting the part # and another unshown function finds the correct search result LI, I'm needing to click the link w/in that element.

Comment: You can get the link with: `li.at('a.results-title')` - then you just put it together with `page.uri` to get the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a pretty cool library the other day that I think will help you with this. It will go to the link you give it and then search for a link with the text that you want and click it. If you are having issues with this let me know.

```
require 'watir'
require 'headless'
require 'csv'

headless = Headless.new
headless.start
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('https://www.milwaukeetool.com/search-results?FullTextKeywords=48-42-5540')
browser.link(text: searchText).when_present.click
```

Comment: Took some finagling but I got it to work, thanks everyone.

Comment: glad I could point you in the right direction! you should edit this answer to include anything that you might have had to do differently

Comment: Don't edit the answer. Leave it as it was answered. A comment would be sufficient to document what was changed.

Comment: I switched the setup away from Mechanize and used Watir as suggested.
    `def resultsPageSearcher (searchText)
        results_sku = @browser.span(:class => 'results-sku')
        if results_sku.text == searchText
            results_sku.element(:xpath => './preceding-sibling::*[1]').click
        end
    end`